# Delete portion of Sub Document Collection in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to delete a section of sub documents from a collections..

Tried (and many others):

```
 db.collection.remove( {'Segments': {$gte: '20150612141038' }} )
 db.collection.remove( { 'Segments.$' : {$gte: '0150612141038' }} )
 db.collection.deleteMany( { 'Segments.$' : {$gte: '0150612141038' }} )
 db.collection.deleteOne( { 'Segments.$' : {$eq: '0150612141038' }} )
```

just can't figure out what I am doing wrong...

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("56e32c5147e030bc0a000035"),
  "Date" : "2015-06-12",
  "UnitID" : "5",
  "Segments" : {
      "20150612141037" : {
        "Parameters" : {
          "647" : "0",
          "649" : "16",
          "653" : "0",
          "655" : "0",
          "656" : "0",
          "658" : "98",
          "664" : "447.0486",
          "666" : "442.7083",
          "677" : "122.8004",
    }
  },
     "20150612141038" : {
       "Parameters" : {
         "658" : "96",
         "664" : "451.3889",
         "666" : "447.0486",
         "677" : "122.7892"
    }
  },
    "20150612141039" : {
       "Parameters" : {
         "658" : "44",
         "664" : "442.7083",
         "677" : "122.8004",
         "704" : "1"
    }
  },
```

Comment: Are you trying to remove the whole document containing those subdocuments or the subdocuments from within the documents?

Comment: I am trying to remove the subdocuments only.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think your queries are wrong. 
If you try this query to the mongoShell:

```
db.bios.find({'Segments': {$gte: '20150612141038'}})
```

you don't have anything as output because `20150612141038` is a document and not a field. Maybe you can reshape your schema to set `20150612141038` as a field and `Segments` as an array of documents:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("56e32c5147e030bc0a000035"),
  "Date" : "2015-06-12",
  "UnitID" : "5",
  "Segments" : [
        {
            "segmentId" : "20150612141037", 
            "Parameters" : {
                "647" : "0", 
                "649" : "16", 
                "653" : "0", 
                "655" : "0", 
                "656" : "0", 
                "658" : "98", 
                "664" : "447.0486", 
                "666" : "442.7083", 
                "677" : "122.8004"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "segmentId" : "20150612141038", 
            "Parameters" : {
                "658" : "96", 
                "664" : "451.3889", 
                "666" : "447.0486", 
                "677" : "122.7892"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "segmentId" : "20150612141039", 
            "Parameters" : {
                "658" : "44", 
                "664" : "442.7083", 
                "677" : "122.8004", 
                "704" : "1"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

and then you can use [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) operator to remove documents from `Segments` array where the field `Segments.segmentId` has a certain value:

```
db.collection.update({},
               {$pull:{Segments:{"segmentId":{$eq:"20150612141039"}}}},
               { multi: true}
               )
```

Comment: I like where this is headed. I have been experimenting on creating the proper schema. I did not like calling the array Segments and it not having a value. I would rather make each time stamp its own top level document, adding date and unitID to each. If I understand you correctly, you are saying to assign the time stamp as a segmentID which will be the sub-doc.

Comment: I ran your query and got back....2016-03-30T13:16:24.812-0400 I CONTROL  [main] Hotfix KB2731284 or later update is not installed, will zero-out data files
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 0, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })      Of course I changed the collection name to properly match.  The Hotfix is installed, when I try to install it, Windows tells me it is installed already.   This has somewhat been my issue, being able to match the sub set of values (timestamps) under Segments.

Comment: It was the update query that did not work. I thought this update query would change the schema to what you suggested sorry.

Comment: No you can use that query with a reshaped schema. 
Can you change your schema?

Comment: Working on changing it via the import that built it. Was hoping there would be some easy Mongo commands to move documents and/or fields, but I am too new to figure it out quickly I believe, if even possible.

Comment: Your Update query reported the following error this time....     "writeError" : {
        "code" : 16837,
        "errmsg" : "Cannot apply $pull to a non-array value"
    }

Comment: Are you sure? It works for me. `Segments` must be an array of documents.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107788/discussion-between-distribuzionegaussiana-and-htm11h).